# Composer installation of drupal console missing functions

Tags: 8, console

I've been attempting to install drupal console for the first time ever. I was looking for a means of creating boiler plate modules, blocks etc.

My issue is when I have finished the installation process, the following list of functions seems incomplete according to everything I have read online. Incomplete because there is only one generate function and nothing to generate blocks, modules etc:

```
Available commands: 
  about                        Displays basic information about Drupal Console project
  chain                        Chain command execution
  check                        System requirement checker
  exec                         Execute an external command.
  help                         Displays help for a command
  init                         Copy configuration files.
  list                         Lists all available commands
  server (serve,rs)            Runs PHP built-in web server
 database
  database:add (dba)           Add a database to settings.php
  database:client (dbc)        Launch a DB client if it's available
  database:connect (dbco,sqlc) Shows DB connection
  database:query (dbq,sqlq)    Executes a SQL statement directly as argument
  database:restore (dbr)       Restore structure and contents of a database.
 debug
  debug:chain (dch)            List available chain files.
  debug:dotenv                 Debug Dotenv debug values.
  debug:settings (dse)         List user Drupal Console settings.
  debug:site (dsi)             List all known local and remote sites.
  debug:update:composer (duc)  Displays current updates available from the composer file
 develop
  develop:contribute           Download Drupal + Drupal Console to contribute.
 docker
  docker:init                  Create a docker-compose.yml file
 dotenv
  dotenv:init                  Add support and required config to work with an .env file
 generate
  generate:site:alias (gsa)    Generates a site alias.
 quick
  quick:start                  Download, install and serve a new Drupal project
 settings
  settings:set                 Change a specific setting value in DrupalConsole config file
 site
  site:install (si)            Install a Drupal project
  site:new                     Download a new Drupal project
```

I used the following command:

```
sudo composer global require drupal/console:@stable
```

**Can anyone pleas advice me on how I can get a more complete list of functions?**

UPDATE:

I don't know if this error showing as the first output when *drupal* is executed in my terminal, has anything to do with my issue:

```
 [ERROR] Class Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel does not exist.
```

So far my attempts to google that error have turned up no solutions.

Comment: Is it a file permission issue since you installed with sudo?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue.  Per some other posts, I've tried starting fresh

1. Deleted drupal/console from composer.json (in docroot)
2. Deleted composer.lock
3. Ran `composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader`
4. Ran `composer update drupal/console --with-dependencies`

`vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal` shows I've got 1.9.3, but the only generate command I get from list is gsa as shown in sisko's post.  I get the same thing in both Drupal 8.5 and Drupal 8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal console is installed on a per Drupal project basis. Install it locally, not globally

```
cd my_drupal_project
composer require drupal/console

# run it from your vendor folder
vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal site:status
```

If you are using Linux or OSX, you can add this line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file

```
alias drupal="/var/www/my_drupal_project/vendor/bin/drupal"
```

The above alias is just an example - you will need to adjust the exact directory path that the alias points to.

Comment: There also is [Drupal Console Launcher](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console-launcher) to have a global wrapper around the local command. Then you can call `$ console` as usual everywhere and it always will find the correct local dependency.

Comment: Nice @leymannx - similar in concept to the drush launcher which is great https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher